# Confused about setting up SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I need to run some basic SQL code for a class assignment, but I'm having trouble setting up an environment to work in. I have xampp downloaded on my Ubuntu machine, but what else do I need to download to make it work? How do I create a SQL document and actually run it?

Comment: If you have XAMPP installed and working you are one step ahead. Simply use `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: Since it's for class, I'm sure you can ask your professor/teacher or TA and they will gladly help you. That's what they're there for.

Comment: What do you mean by use phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use   **phpMyAdmin** for the practice. Create database there and  practice.

You can access to that by type in your browser **http://localhost/phpmyadmin**

Comment: For some reason, typing that into my browswer window gives me an error message. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You could write SQL against some online databases and test it without setting up a local environment.

http://sqlzoo.net/

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp